# Mysterious errors importing numpy and scipy with "knee.py"

Tags: python, import, module, numpy, scipy

There's a file included with the Python source called `knee.py`. It overrides the regular import statement with it's own hook. The code is supposed to be correct, and for builtin modules and single file modules, it is. However, I get a bizarre error (both different) when I try to import numpy with it.

```
(...long stack trace)
  File "knee.py", line 101, in import_module
    m = imp.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
TypeError: import_hook() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)
```

I don't get why this would happen? Could it be that there's a `self` being passed as well? None of the code in `knee.py` is written for an object, and I'm pretty sure that `imp.load_module` doesn't expect a `self` argument. Does anyone have an idea as to what could be causing the problem? I even kept a record of what was getting imported, and it seems that the code doesn't run into the problem right away, only after it's imported some other things in numpy.

For the case with scipy, I get an error, which may be related to the numpy incident:

```
(...long stack trace)
  File "/usr/apps/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import _sort
  File "knee.py", line 16, in import_hook
    q, tail = find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "knee.py", line 52, in find_head_package
    q = import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "knee.py", line 101, in import_module
    m = imp.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be going on?

Comment: Have you tried it with another python C extension?  (Say, `cStringIO` or something else in the standad library?)  I don't really have a clue either, but it would help to narrow it down to whether it's a numpy-specific issue or a general C-extension issue...

Comment: `cStringIO` worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED.** *(only guaranteeing solution for packaged modules numpy and scipy)*

I implemented my own solution. Be wary that while the code I post here works, it contains a bunch of silly debug statements and commented out code that can be removed, as well as doing a couple of other things that are related to what I wanted to use this for.

My solution: [mknee.py](http://acm.uiuc.edu/~tkadic2/mknee.py)

Comment: Tsk tsk tsk - broken link